# How do we prove that given a set S such that |S|=|SxS| then |P(S)|=|P(S)xP(S)| where P(S) is the power set of S?

Tags: set-theory

Given a bijection f from S to SxS, I can't seem to find an appropriate mapping from P(S) to P(S)xP(S). I don't know if I am missing something obvious but I have tried making a connection through P(SxS) as well but to no avail.
Edit: I'm especially interested in the case of S being the natural numbers as I want to use this and prove that |R|=|R^2|.

Comment: Can you give an example of a set $S$ such that $|S|=|S\times S|$? The claim you are trying to prove is false. Perhaps you meant $|P(S)|=|P(S\times S)|$?

Comment: @Couchy For the set of natural numbers for example this condition holds.

Comment: @Couchy: Is it false? The assertion is true in ZFC (because AC gives you the answer); is there a model of ZF where it is false?

Comment: $P(S)\times P(S) \sim  2^S\times 2^S \sim 2^{S\amalg S}$, while $P(S\times S)=2^{S\times S}$. So perhaps you should see if you can use the bijection $S\sim S\times S$ to find a bijection $S\amalg S\sim S\times S$, where $S\amalg S$ is the disjoint union. (For $|S|\neq 1$, anyway...)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This doesn't work when $S$ is the singleton, no fancy set theory :)

Comment: @Couchy: Fair enough; but if you take the singleton away...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a bijection between $\Bbb{P}(\Bbb{N})$ and $\Bbb{P}(\Bbb{N}) \times \Bbb{P}(\Bbb{N})$ by:
$$
A \mapsto (\{ i \in \Bbb{N} \mid 2i \in A\}, \{ j \in \Bbb{N} \mid 2j+1 \in A\})
$$
and that will give you that $|\Bbb{R}| = |\Bbb{R}^2|$. [Space filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) give another (and perhaps more entertaining) take on the latter fact.

Comment: It just so happened that I stumbled upon this bijection just before you posted this. Anyway, thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is empty or infinite, then $P(S)$ is respectively a singleton or an infinite set, and so $P(S)$ is in bijection with $P(S) \times P(S)$.

The statement does not hold, however, if $S$ is a singleton. In this case, $\vert P(S) \vert=2$, while $\vert P(S) \times P(S) \vert=4$.

Comment: This assumes AC; I expect the intention is to show that *if* you happen to have a bijection $S\sim S\times S$, then you should be able to use that to construct a bijection $P(S)\sim P(S)\times P(S)$ that does not invoke the heavy hammer of "every infinite set is bijectable with its square", which by Tarski's theorem, is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How can we prove the result in the case of S being the naturals without invoking the Axiom of Choice? My intention is to use this to prove that |R^2|=|R|

Comment: @GiannisVlachodimitropoulos: then perhaps put that information into the post? As written, as has been pointed out, you would need to exclude the case of $S$ being a singleton. And you should say that you want an *explicit* bijection between $P(\mathbb{N})$ and $P(\mathbb{N})\times P(\mathbb{N})$, instead of a general statement.

Answer (score 0):

This argument can be formalized in Zermelo set theory or New Foundations. Let QX be the non-empty subsets of X.

There is a 1-1 map from QSxQT to Q(SxT).

Proof: The map which sends (A,B) to AxB is such a map.

Suppose there is a 1-1 map from SxT to S, S is not empty and T has at least 2 elements. Then S has a denumerable subset.

Proof: Suppose s∈S,a≠b, a∈T, b∈T, and f is a 1-1 map from SxT to T.Define a sequence cn by c0=f(s,a) and c(n+1)=f(cn,b).

Suppose S contains a denumerable subset and s∉S. Then there is a 1-1 function from SU{s} to S.

Proof:Let bn for n a natural number be distinct elements of S. Define a function from SU{s} to S by fs=b0,f(bn)=b(n+1), and fx=x for other elements of S.

Suppose S is not empty, T has at least 2 elements, and there is a 1-1 function from SxT to S. Then P(SxT) is equipollent with PSxPT.

Proof:Since SxT is equipollent with S, and there is a 1-1 function from PS to PSxPT, there is a 1-1 function from P(SxT) to PSxPT.
Suppose s∈S,and t∈T. S-{s} contains a denumerable set and consequently it is equipollent with S. There is a 1-1 function from QSxQT to Q((S-{s})xT). Since QS contains a denumerable set, QS is
equipolllent with PS. Consequently there is a 1-1 function g from PSxQT to Q((S-{s})xT).Since there is 1-1 function from S to S-{s}, there is a 1-1 function p from PS to  P(S-{s}). Define a 1-1
function q from PS to PS by qA=pAU{s}. Extend g to a function f with domain PSxPT by putting f(A,∅)=(qA)x{t}, for A contained in S.Then f is a 1-1 function from PSxPT to P(SxT). Since there is a
1-1 function from P(SxT) to PSxPT and a 1-1 function from PSxPT to P(SxT), P(SxT) is equipollent with PSxPT.

Taking S=T above and considering what happens when S=∅, we see that if S is not a singleton, and SxS is equipollent with S, then PS is equipollent with PSxPS.